# Any regulated function on $[a, b]$ is bounded - proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I would like to verify that my proof on the following statement is correct:

> Any [regulated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function) on $[a, b]$ is bounded.

Let $f \in R[a, b]$ (the space of regulated functions on $[a, b]$) be any regulated function.

Then, by definition, $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists \phi \in S[a, b]$ (the space of step functions on $[a, b]$) such that $\|\phi - f\|_\infty < \varepsilon$. Note that all step functions are bounded, i.e. $\phi [a, b]$ is a bounded function.

Now, by definition, $\|\phi - f\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in [a, b]}|\phi - f| < \varepsilon$.

Since the supremum of a function can only be bounded if the function is bounded, it follows that $|\phi - f|$ is a bounded function. But $\phi$ is bounded, so $f$ must also be a bounded function.

i.e. any regulated function on $[a, b]$ is bounded.

Comment: What is a regulated function?

Comment: @copper.hat Sorry, I thought it was common notation, what alternative names are there for it? (edited my question)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have never seen the notation, but that doesn't mean that it is not common.

Comment: @copper.hat If it helps with any missing background, it's usually seen straight after step functions (since that's what they are defined on).

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me.